# SAPUI5 Northwind and mockServer

Tags: sapui5

I am setting up a Mockserver to do unit tests on a sapui5 project, but I did not understand how to Northwind worked, I have some questions please:

- How my data JSON and Northwind data are linking?
- Does my data have to come from an API for mockServer?
- How do you generate our data with Northwind?

I think I understood the operation of the mockServer but not Northwind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get mocking working with any ODATA service you need following files

1. mockserver.html (replica of an index.html file with few tweaks mentioned in API documentation)
2. mockserver.js to start the mock server
3. metadata.xml (which you can obtain via adding $metadata at the end of the service URL)
4. json file with data to represent the entity your are working on like Products.json or Users.json with dummy data.

Have a look at this url for more info
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bae9d90d2e9c4206889368f04edab508

Direct Answers to your questions:

**How is my data JSON and Northwind data is linking?** it is via metadata.xml

**Does my data have to come from an API for mockServer?** No data will come from a mock server which is actually going to get it from JSON file.

**How do you generate our data with Northwind?** Just create json file with dummy data. You don't need data from Northwind. Or just open their endpoint in browser and copy it from there. It is very simple